# How to extract all pages of one big pdf file?

Tags: linux, command-line

I need a tip how to extract all pages from big pdf file in command line.
Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "extract all pages"?  Do you mean to extract each page of the PDF into its own PDF file, or into some other file format?

Comment: You might check [this](http://www.fytek.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=105)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wanna extract all pages from a pdf file, You need pdftk:

http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Do you use a debian's like distro?
Do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Once installed, do:

```
$ pdftk file.pdf burst
```

****Another tip, create a new directory before split your pdf file to take your files organized**

Answer (score 3):

To manage PDF you can use PDF Toolkit.
On Debian based distribution you can install with:

```
apt-get install pdftk
```

Is written in `Java` and require `gcj`.

You can create a new file for every page with:

```
pdftk BIG-FILE.pdf burst
```

You can also use the `pdftk cat command` to split some pages: please read the manual.

If you want to convert PDF files you can pick an utility from the bunch of `poppler-utils`.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be wanting to just extract specific sets of pages, I found Linux Mint 18 came with something called `pdfseparate`.  Not sure if that applies to your distro, but for me it meant I didn't need to install anything.

This let me do things like make a new PDF with just the first page (still in the original vector format, if applicable):

`pdfseparate -f 1 -l 1 original.pdf just-page-one-of-original.pdf`

(Why?  Because another piece of software was annoyingly adding a blank page at the end of its PDF output.)