# How to extract pages 3, 4, 5 from a PDF from Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf, imagemagick

Note: I have already found solutions for Linux (see [How to extract all pages of one big pdf file?](https://superuser.com/questions/372061/how-to-extract-all-pages-of-one-big-pdf-file)) or solutions with Python, or solutions with freeware GUI tools.

**How do I extract specific pages from a PDF on Windows, from command line (no GUI tool), and keep the original format (i.e. if it's a text input PDF, the output should not be an image PDF)?**

I already tried with ImageMagick:

```
convert input.pdf[2,3,4] output.pdf                # numbering begins at 0, so [2,3,4] is for pages 3,4,5
```

and it works, but the output file is a PDF containing *images*, so it's much bigger than the input, and you cannot search by text inside the output PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I extract specific pages from a PDF on Windows, from command line (no GUI tool), and keep the original format (i.e. if it's a text input PDF, the output should not be an image PDF)?

[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (the tool mentioned in the accepted answer to your [linked question](https://superuser.com/questions/372061/how-to-extract-all-pages-of-one-big-pdf-file)) can do this. It is a cross-platform utility and offers builds for Windows. For performing operations from the command-line, you would want [PDFtk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/).

Looking at the [command-line examples](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) for PDFtk Server, your example command would be something like:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 3-5 output extracted.pdf
```

**Notes**

- PDFtk Server appeared to produce text from a handful of text PDFs when tested (i.e. text in "extracted" PDFs could be highlighted, copied and searched as normal).
- Regarding licensing, [PDFtk Server is currently released under the GPL](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-license/).